# Preserve matrix column & row titles while converting character to numeric

Tags: r, matrix, character, transpose, numeric

I have a matrix that I recently transposed that converted the numeric numbers into character numbers:

[image]
[image]

So, I used as.numeric to convert the cells back to numeric like such:

```
cyc_daily_v5 <- matrix(as.numeric(cyc_daily_v4), ncol=ncol(cyc_daily_v4))
```

However, this converted my column & row title headings as well:

[image]

Is there a way I can retain the original day of the week column titles during the character-to-numeric conversion?

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can share the output of running `dput(cyc_daily_v4)` in the body of your question, instead of pictures.

Comment: Assuming, as in your example, you don't have any values that can't be expressed as numeric, you can use `type.convert(cyc_daily_v4, as.is = TRUE)`.

Comment: @JonSpring Ah, noted for next time!

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I gave this a try, and that worked too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transfer the row and column names into your newly created data frame. Feel free to let me know if it worked.

```
cnames = colnames(cyc_daily_v4)
rnames = rownames(cyc_daily_v4)
cyc_daily_v5 = as.data.frame(cyc_daily_v5)
rownames(cyc_daily_v5) = rnames
colnames(cyc_daily_v5) = cnames
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `storage.mode()`:

```r
test_mat <- matrix(c("1", "2", "4", "5", "6", "7"), ncol = 2)
dimnames(test_mat) <- list(c("a", "b", c"), c("AA", "BB"))

test_mat
#   AA  BB 
# a "1" "5"
# b "2" "6"
# c "4" "7"

storage.mode(test_mat) <- "numeric"
test_mat
#   AA BB
# a  1  5
# b  2  6
# c  4  7
```